# Optimal way to place a given number of points in a region?

Tags: optimization, discrete-geometry

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}²$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be a given natural number. How to find a finite subset of $A$, $P=${$p_1,...,p_n$} such that $\int_A f_P(x)$ is minimum, where $f_P(x) = min${$d(x,p_1),...,d(x,p_n)$} and $d$ is the usual distance?
Supose a certain number of hospitals must be placed in a city. How should them be placed so that on average the length from any point in the city to the nearest hospital is the less as possible?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: If the usual distance is used, the resulting function $f_P$ is composed of 'parts' of surfaces of cones.

Comment: This sounds non trivial. You might want to read about Centroidal Voronoi Tessellations (relate, though not quite the same thing -minimizes average square distance rather than average distance)  and perhaps k-medians clustering (for samples instead of a distribution).